# C++ SAFEARRAY has invalid data when returned from c# COM dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com

i try to get data ( in form of a class/struct array ) from a c# dll in c++. i tried to work with the safearray helper function but all data i recived is invalid....

while debugging everything works/looks perfect untill i reach the point to recive data that was generated in the dll ( only the SAFEARRAY* looks invalid ) , so maybe it is a problem with the communication between C++ application and the c# COM dll
[VS SAFEARRAY Debug/Auto Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Jzr.jpg)
[VS DownloadList Debug/Auto Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQXml.jpg)

here is a code example :
C#

```
// data class
public class Download
{
    public string Target;
    public string Data;
    public int Port;
}

// function called from outside dll
public Download[] GetData()
{
    [...]
    return DownloadList.ToArray(); // List<Download>
}
```

C++

```
#import "[...]/MSSQL_Lib.tlb"
// pDB is a class instance which contain the GetData func
[...]
SAFEARRAY* Data = pDB->GetData();
if( Data != nullptr )
{
    // print varian type info from result
    SafeArrayLock( Data );

    VARIANT* ValueArray = (VARIANT*)Data->pvData;
    long Lower = 0, Upper = 0;
    SafeArrayGetLBound( Data, 1, &Lower );
    SafeArrayGetUBound( Data, 1, &Upper );

    for( long i = 0; i <= ( Upper - Lower ); ++i )
    {
        PrintVariant( &ValueArray[i] );
    }

    SafeArrayUnlock( Data );
    SafeArrayDestroy( Data );
}
[...]
// function end

void PrintVariant( VARIANT* pV )
{
    switch( pV->vt )
    {
        case VT_BSTR:
            wprintf( L" String : %s \n", pV->bstrVal );
            break;
        default:
            wprintf( L" Unrecognized Type : %d \n", pV->vt );
            break;
    }
}
```

i also tried to marshal the c# class :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class Download
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string Target;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string Data;
    public int Port;
}
```

but same result. with marshal i get this warning : "Type library exporter warning processing '[...].Download, [...]'. Warning: The reference type had sequential or explicit layout, and so was exported as a struct." but i guess it should not result in completly invalid returned data

print results looks like :

```
 Unrecognized Type : 65432
 Unrecognized Type : 65048
 Unrecognized Type : 64664
 Unrecognized Type : 64280
 Unrecognized Type : 1
 Unrecognized Type : 0
 Unrecognized Type : 0
 Unrecognized Type : 43008
 Unrecognized Type : 21288
 Unrecognized Type : 1331
```

but they change every run a little bit.

So i hope anyone could help me and find the detail i missed^^
thx for reading and feel free to ask for more details

Comment: i dont know if it is usefull, but the idear is based on : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16206/Call-C-code-from-C-and-read-an-array-of-struct-whi

Comment: Can you show the MIDL?

Comment: Offtopic, but unless there is a requirement for COM, best practices today for interop between c++ and .NET when one has access to the c++ source code, is to change the c++ project to c++/CLI.  Everyone talks .NET then without all the tedious marshalling of native types or the complexities of COM.

Comment: @MickyD the problem is i have 'heavy' uasge of std::thread and other CLI incomplatible classes ( also cannot use boost::thread ) so COM was the only solution i found to work with c# dll in c++. if i dont find any solution to this i have to redesign the whole application for cli, but it will take weeks...
sry for asking, but what do you mean exactly with "show MIDL" ? ( maybe the tlh/tlb file ? )

Comment: The array you get with SafeArrayLOck is always based on 0, not on lower bound, so you need only the size between lower and upper bound and start with 0. But this may not the problem. But your code is wrong.

Comment: @xMRi oh, thx - changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is not an array of VARIANT but an array of IUnknown* (a call to SafeArrayGetVartype would have told you that). You'll have to change your code for something like this:

```
SAFEARRAY *psa = pDB->GetData();
if (psa)
{
    SafeArrayLock(psa);
    LONG lb;
    LONG ub;
    SafeArrayGetLBound(psa, 1, &lb);
    SafeArrayGetUBound(psa, 1, &ub);
    for (int i = lb; i <= ub; i++)
    {
        _DownloadPtr download(((IUnknown**)psa->pvData)[i]);
        wprintf(L"%s\n", (LPWSTR)download->GetTarget());
    }
    SafeArrayUnlock(psa);
}
```

Note it means your Download class must also be marked as `[ComVisible(true)]`, and the fields be transformed into public properties. Because you need an IUnknown interface in this example (to see methods such as GetTarget() automatically added to the generated C++ code), I also suggest you add a `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` attribute to it.

If you do want array of VARIANTs (why would you?), then you'll have to use `object[]` instead of typed objects.arrays.

Comment: nice :), so the SAFEARRAY contains uuid's of each result 'Download' instance ? when i dont marshal the download class i will get an empty class ( no members ) in the .tlh file - if i marshal the class i dont have a constructor that accept the uuid

Comment: the SAFEARRAY contains an array of pointers to IUknown interfaces, not uuid (=Guid). The Download class must be marked as ComVisible(true), there's no need to add any marshal attributes.

Comment: Not the only problem.  Only public properties are accessible, not fields.  Exposing the data as a struct instead of a class is another approach, but structs are not very pretty in COM.

Comment: @HansPassant - good point, I did my tests with properties w/o even noticing they were not in the original question :-)

Comment: hmm, i dont get the download class to be fully exported to tlh file ( yes its marked as com visible ). its result in an empty struct allways, even with public properties @HansPassant

Comment: @ChristophP - Add a `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` attribute to it so it has an IUnknow* interface (not only IDispatch) (you'll need ro run regasm again to get a new tlb)